# How do I change the size of an HBox in Flex to fit its container?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, button, mxml, hbox

I create an HBox, fill it with a grid of buttons, and set the scroll policy. When I resize the window, the stage changes size, and so does the HBox ... to a point. Once it reaches the height of the Grid it contains, it stops shrinking, like it has a "min-height". This ruins the scrollbar that I'm trying to establish in this case.

I've set the height to 100%, shouldn't it always take the height of the stage, its parent?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<mx:Application 
xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
initialize="init();" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off" width="100%"> 

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Button;
        import mx.containers.Grid;
        import mx.containers.GridRow;
        import mx.containers.GridItem;

        protected function init():void {    
            for (var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                var gRow:GridRow = new GridRow();
                gRow.percentWidth = 100;
                gRow.height = 100;
                var gItem:GridItem = new GridItem();
                gItem.percentWidth = 100;
                var btn:Button = new Button();
                btn.label = "BUTTON";
                btn.percentWidth = 100;
                btn.percentHeight = 100;
                gItem.addChild(btn);
                gRow.addChild(gItem);
                mainGrid.addChild(gRow);
            }       
        }         
  ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="on" id="main" clipContent = "true">
    <mx:Grid id="mainGrid" width="100%" height="100%" />
</mx:HBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like I managed to mention the eventual answer in my question. It's the `"minHeight"` property folks, looks like it gets set to the contained grids height, and will shrink no smaller. Set it to 0, and your good to go.

I hope this dialog I'm having with myself helps someone *else*. :)

Comment: +1 You've answered your own question. Two more votes and you'll get a self learner badge :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to give it the heigh of the HBox, as height="{hb.height}" ,hb as id

Comment: I could certainly set the HBox to reflect the height of the stage, but the whole reason I'm using Flex is because the Layout manager is supposed to handle that. I feel like I'm just missing a setting somewhere.